# Filter rows by value1, if not use the other - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**Column 1 "Letter":** A, B, C
**Column 2 "Name":** Apple, Boat, Cat

I need a query to get the name value if the letter value equal to A. In case that no A, so return the name for B. So, I need to get one record at the end.

Please help

Comment: What would the output of your query be here?

Comment: My output will be A and if A doesn't exist, it will be B

Comment: Do you want the `name` value returned (as per the question) or the `letter` value (as per your previous comment)? If it is the former then should your previous comment not be "My output will be Apple and if a row with the letter A doesn't exist it will be Boat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by `letter` and, from Oracle 12, `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`:

```
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY letter
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

or, in earlier versions, order and then filter by the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name
  FROM   table_name
  ORDER BY letter
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```

If you only want `A` or `B` values then add a `WHERE` filter:

```
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  letter IN ('A', 'B')
ORDER BY letter
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  letter IN ('A', 'B')
  ORDER BY letter
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```

Which, for your sample data, output:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | Apple |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lwTQTCkk)

Comment: What about if column 1 has text value which is not ordered alphabetically and column 2 has numbers and I want to apply same query idea

Comment: @user3315201 For that, you can use `ORDER BY CASE letter WHEN 'A' THEN 1 WHEN 'C' THEN 2 WHEN 'B' THEN 3 END` and then put the values in whatever priority order you want for sorting.

Comment: it is resolved ....Thank you very much for your great help

Comment: But what about if we have three columns and we want to group the data by the first column

Comment: @user3315201 If you have a different problem then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask); do not keep trying to change the problem in comments.